# Typescript Method overload with "identical signature"

Tags: typescript, methods, overloading

Consider this code:

```
class Socket extends EventEmitter {
...
        on(event: string, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this;
        on(event: "close", listener: () => void): this;
        on(event: "connect", listener: () => void): this;
        on(event: "error", listener: (err: Error) => void): this;
        on(event: "listening", listener: () => void): this;
        on(event: "message", listener: (msg: Buffer, rinfo: RemoteInfo) => void): this;
...
}
```

From module "dgram" in typescript / node.js type definition file, this is "the" udp server from node.js. The code is in the "dgram.d.ts" file.

When I write Socket.on(" in Visual Studio Code to use it, it resolves the first parameter of this method to be: close, connect,error,listening, message, as if it would be an enumeration.

I can't even name the correct term for this "mechanism", what is this? Normally in a parameter the leftside of it would be the variable name and the right side the type example (event:string). But here it looks like a literal string is again a valid type and its so smart that it can resolve it in the overloads example (event: "close")
If I would use something like myparameter:"myliteralString" in a simple single function it would not even make sense, it makes only sense in combination with overloads as far as I understand.

If you can just name me the concepts or whats happening here behind the scenes (like implicitly building arrays or something like this,  which make this work. I'm happy, I just want to understand it.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you looking for documentation for [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types)?  Or maybe something like [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), since, while overload signatures don't quite constitute such a union, you can [refactor it into one](https://tsplay.dev/NBzEDN).  Literal types make sense when you care about particular values; I wouldn't say it doesn't make sense to have a function like `foo(x: "onlyThis"): void`, but it isn't very useful.

Comment: This was the literature what i was looking for, "literal types" thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to [Overload Signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature) ?

Maybe the type of event is defined like this:

[image]

Comment: This was the literature what i was looking for, "literal types" thank you!